# PDF/A-1b: Bibliography: width information for rendered glyphs is inconsistent

Tags: fonts, bibliographystyle, pdf-a

The goal is to create a **PDF/a-1b** compliant document. The document contains more that 100 pages with tens of formulae, tables and figures. The problem is the following error that occurs several times only on the pages of bibliography:

> *width information for rendered glyphs is inconsistent* in bibliography
> pages.

The bibliography is defined as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-1b,usecharset]{pdfx}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{external.bib}

@inproceedings{machacek-bojar-2014-results,
    title        = {Results of the {WMT}14 Metrics Shared Task},
    author       = {Mach{\'a}{\v{c}}ek, Matou{\v{s}}  and Bojar, Ond{\v{r}}ej},
    year         = 2014,
    month        = jun,
    booktitle    = {Proceedings of the Ninth Workshop on Statistical Machine Translation},
    publisher    = {Association for Computational Linguistics},
    address      = {Baltimore, Maryland, USA},
    pages        = {293--301},
    doi          = {10.3115/v1/W14-3336},
    url          = {https://aclanthology.org/W14-3336}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, sorting=none, style=gost-numeric, language=autobib, autolang=other, clearlang=true, defernumbers=true, sortcites=true,
doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{external.bib}
\title{mwe}
\date{June 2022}
\begin{document}
\cite{machacek-bojar-2014-results}
\section{Introduction}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a full example, not just a code snippet … But generally, sounds like potentially an issue with your font not having a a font descriptor, or something like that. Are you using the MnSymbol or mdsymbol packages?

Comment: @Ingmar Thank you very much for your comment! I am not using neither `MnSymbol` nor `mdsymbol`. I have more than 100 page document full of formulas, figures and tables. According to the Adobe Acrobat the problem is only in the bibliography so I assume that's something wrong with the `biblatex` definition.

Comment: @Ingmar a short MWE has been added

Comment: @moewe, Thank you very much for your comment! I've added the `\usepackage[a-1b,usecharset]{pdfx}` with the Acrobat verification error message.

Comment: I have rewritten your MWE to include the .bib into the actual file, so it's easier to copy, paste & run.

Comment: Are you really using the LaTeX default font? That said, when I change  the fontenc to `\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}` to actually get it to compile, the result validates as PDF/A-1B with VeraPDF.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately I don't have Acrobat, so I don't think I can help a lot, but what I would suggest to try and isolate the problem is to see if you can reproduce the problem without the bibliography by just writing the relevant text manually (obviously with the current formatting).